# jQuery: preventing event from executing for duration of animation

Tags: jquery, events, animation, slider

OK, I've checked this thread:

[Prevent click event in jQuery triggering multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012447/prevent-click-event-in-jquery-triggering-multiple-times)

- and attempted to unbind/re-bind an event as described but to no avail. I basically have a slider gallery, with a next/prev button. I want to prevent the next button from being clicked for the duration of the animation.

  ```
  prev = $("#portfolio_nav_prev");
  next = $("#portfolio_nav_next");

  function nextAnim(){
      //remove handler
      next.unbind();

      gallery_frame.animate({scrollLeft:targetPos}, 300, 'easeInOutQuart',function(){next.bind(nextAnim)});
      return false;
      }
  ```

any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to create an unresponsive interface? Instead, you should just `.stop()` the current animation when you click a button.

Comment: because the interface needs to complete a slider animation before accepting any more events, or else it breaks the slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I ended up using - the problem was that the element was an anchor, so when I unbound the click animation - it tried to navigate away from the page, thus breaking the animation.

So, I unbound the event, then made click bind to return false:

```
next.unbind();
next.click(function(){return false;})
```

Then did the same in the animation callback, but binding it back to the animation.

```
gallery_frame.animate({scrollLeft:targetPos}, 300, 'easeInOutQuart',
function()next.unbind();next.bind('click',nextAnim)});
```

However, I think the real solution is to make the next/prev buttons out of some non-anchor element in the first place.