# ajax/jquery - prevent user from clicking multiple times

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an div witch has and a jquery listner for it:

```
$("#right_arrow").click(function(){
  //my action
});
```

My action is also counting steps and if user gets to last step it wont let it go further. When user clicks div normally everything is allright. But when user clicks two times very fast (at prevoios to last step) then he passes the last step.

I have tried something like this:

```
if($(this).data('off')==1) return;
$(this).data('off', 1);
//my action
$(this).data('off',0);
```

But still have the same problem. It seems that anything i write inside the function doesent matter - like the two clicks que up even before lunching the function for the first time.

How can that be avoided?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1012447/875127, http://stackoverflow.com/q/6064232/875127,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably more costly to try to detach and reattach an event handler each click, you can use a boolean flag to indicate whether it's safe to click or not.

```
var isClicked = false;

$("#right_arrow").click(function(){
  if (!isClicked) {
    isClicked = true;

    //my action

    // reenable in 200ms
    setTimeout(function () {
      isClicked = false;
    }, 200);
  }
});
```

Comment: I have no idea, it worked for me, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

use mouse out event to set it off like:

```
    $("#right_arrow").click(function(){
        if($(this).attr('data-off')==1) return;
        $(this).attr('data-off', 1);
        //my action
        $(this).mouseout(function(){
           $(this).attr('data-off',0);
        });

     });
```